# Mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to create a batch to backup MySQL database using task scheduler..

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 DELIMS=/ " %%F IN ('date /T') DO (set v_date=%%F%%G%%H) 
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 DELIMS=: " %%F IN ('time /T') DO (set v_time=%%F%%G%%H) 
set fname=database_backup_%v_date%_%v_time%.sql    
echo %v_time% 
echo %fname% 
set desfolder=C:\backup
set desfolder1=D:\backup
echo %desfolder%
echo %desfolder1%

mysqldump --add-drop-table -u root -pxxxx xxxx>%desfolder%\%fname% 
mysqldump --add-drop-table -u root -pxxxx xxxx>%desfolder1%\%fname% 
pause
```

This particular code worked fine for XP but when coming to Windows task schedule I get the following error:

`mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file`

but if operate it manually it works fine

Answer (score 3):

Do you have mysqldump in your path?

Either

1. add it to the path, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.1/en/mysql-installation-windows-path.html
2. Add the full paths to mysqldump within the script

Comment: Thanks for Reply Marcel, but i have placed the batch file in ProgramFile\Mysql\bin

Comment: Ah, try using the short path instead. c:/PROGRA~1/mysql/bin

Comment: I think its not matter with location because its working fine for windows xp and even for some windows, while some systems are creating the backupfile but its empty. But if we double click it there it self it works fine. Dont know why its not working with task scheduler