# mysqldump wrong command for execution

Tags: php, mysql

I try to backup  my database. I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $command = 'mysqldump --user=root --host=localhost opencart_status > backup.sql';
    $result = passthru($command);
    if(!$result){
        echo "Error!";
    }
    else{
        echo "OK";
    }
?>
```

I have no password to connect to the server with the database. The database that I need to backup is called `opencart_status`.

The output basckup.sql is made, but has 0 B size and is empty. And the output that I see on the screen is Error! I tried also the `exec()` function. But with the same result.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: what error do you see on your screen?

Comment: @Bfcm Only the `echo "Error!"` because `$result = passthru($command);` is false.

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be in port or in the command you use. Try following code:

```
<?php
    $command = 'mysqldump --host=localhost:3306 --user=root opencart_status > backup.sql';
    system($command);
?>
```

Comment: I tried to edit localhost and added :80 port, but the same wrong.

Comment: Yes, but the same result. Besides my setting is _Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.12 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80_

Comment: Your Apache server is not your MySQL server

Comment: OK, my fault. I have PID 4464 and port 3306, but with 3306 I have the same error.

Comment: Like Ingus has said, system, exec or passthru command don't return any response. So your error check is always invalid. 
Do following thing: delete your backup.sql and check if it will be created.

Comment: It's created, but it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you look up `passthru` documentation, you should see that `passthru` does not return any value regarding execution status. If you need a return value to check, you should add a second parameter which is defined as `$return_var` in the documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Most likely you should start with checking that value instead of function return value.

Afterwards I would recommend you to try to run the `mysqldump` command from commandline. You should be able to debug the `mysqldump` problem in the console and afterwards just move it to the php for execution.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have one maybe stupid question. You wrote about commandline. Do you think Windows commandline or what commandline?

Comment: Yes, try the command on windows command line and see what is being outputed. you can even start without the output redirection to file: `mysqldump --user=root --host=localhost opencart_status`

Comment: I got this answer: _'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file._

Comment: This is a problem of mysqldump not available for execution. That might be some issue with paths, like in this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342215/mysqldump-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program

Comment: You showed me right way! I need to run the command in shell from the place, where sql server is installed. For example _D:\xampp\mysql\bin_